# Where in the source code for libre office can I find the excel file parser?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Where in the [source code for libre office](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/) can I find the code for reading, lexing, and parsing Microsoft excel files? The reason I ask is that the canonical python libraries for processing files:

- `openpyxl`
- `xlsxwriter`
- `xlrd`
- `xlwt`
- `xlutils`

... can ***write*** charts and images to file, but they cannot ***read*** charts and images from file. I was hoping to load a chart from file, edit it, and then write it back to file. Given that libre office can read excel files, I figured that, after a lot of work, I could adapt their code to do it.

Comment: Have you decided against a Python-UNO macro? There are examples of reading and writing charts using LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 2):

In old libreoffice 3.4 version the excel filter is at path: root/filter/source/msfilter/mscodec.cxx

In current version of libreoffice it is at core / sc/source/filter/excel/

Source documentation is at :
https://docs.libreoffice.org/sc/html/dir_82f47edfd04c30571642bb04025a7d49.html

God luck with your huge work.